# Show only particular values in drop down list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is there any way to show only some particular values in a Data Validation dropdown list.

I mean a party name must be shown in dropdown list, based on their party type cell value.

I have no idea what formula or vba I should use, so no formula or vba code is written.

This is similar to the dependent dropdown list but not entirely so.

I need a formula or VBA Code which only show **Job Work** parties in Dropdown Data Validation List for multiple cells So **Pivot Table** is not a good suggestion.

***Please refer following image:***

[image]

***See final Result Image Below.***

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste data to your post instead of image so that we can copy to our excel to build formula. Also show your own effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't achieve it directly. You need a helper column. If you have `Office365` then follow below steps. Use `FILTER()` formula to extract `Party Name` for `Job Work` Type. Use below formula.

```
=FILTER(A2:A9,B2:B9="Job Work")
```

[image]

Then in data validation source use filtered list like below (As per screenshot).

```
=$D$2#
```

[image]

> If you do not have `Office365` then have to apply few others formula. Then a `NamedRange` will suitable for you to that helper column.

Comment: Dear Mr. Harun24HR, Thank You for your quick reply. You give me a best solution. But i don't have Office365. and Microsoft Office don't have FILTER Formula.
So Can you please help me with Microsoft office?

Answer (score 0):

you can use name and indirect function, for example create a name like "Send" and include the list of party names in this name using Name Manager and use Indirect function inside data validation formula like "=Indirect(Name)"

following link for example

https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need a formula to filter `Party Name` by `Party Type`. Use below formula to do that.

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$9)/($B$1:$B$9="Job Work"),ROW(2:2))),"")
```

[image]

Then add a Name Manager `PartyName` with below formula (See screenshot).

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$100))
```

[image]

Now in validation list use `PartyName` as source. See below.

[image]